# Identificar URLs e criar links

Tags: javascript, java

Se eu tenho um texto, por exemplo:

> Acesse o www.stackoverflow.com para tirar suas dúvidas.

Como eu faço para identificar a URL e criar um link para ela:

```
Acesse o <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a> para tirar suas dúvidas.
```

De preferência usando JavaScript ou Java.

Comment: Você tem um texto onde exatamente?

Comment: JavaScript e Java são bem diferentes, e usados em situações bem diferentes. Poderia esclarecer em que situação precisa disso? No servidor ou no cliente?

Comment: Iss mesmo @bfavaretto, no front e no back-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para realizar essa tarefa, a técnica é a mesma usada para BBCode. Você precisa utilizar expressões regulares para identificar possíveis URL's e substituilas por âncoras preenchidas.

Eu criei uma expressão para exemplificar com javascript: http://rubular.com/r/btYgux8UTc

Após criada a expressão para isolar as possíveis URL's, você usara a função `String.prototype.replace` para substituir estas pelas ancoras, recuperando a parte principal para a hyper text reference (`href`).

**Veja um exemplo:**

```
var

    reURL = /((?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?:www(\d)?\.)?([\w\-]+\.\w{2,})\/?((?:\?(?:[\w\-]+(?:=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:&[\w\-]+(?:=[\w\-]+)?)?))?(#(?:[^\s]+)?)?)/g,

    text = 'Acesse o www.stackoverflow.com para tirar suas dúvidas.',

    html = text.replace(reURL, '<a href="http$2://www$3.$4$5$6">$1</a>');
```

Neste caso a variável `html` passa a conter o mesmo valor que text, porém substituindo as URL's por âncoras.

Você também pode criar uma função para tornar isso mais eficiente:

```
String.prototype.URLToAnchors = function() {

    return this.replace(/((?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?:www(\d)?\.)?([\w\-]+\.\w{2,})\/?((?:\?(?:[\w\-]+(?:=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:&[\w\-]+(?:=[\w\-]+)?)?))?(#(?:[^\s]+)?)?)/g, '<a href="http$2://www$3.$4$5">$1</a>');

}
```

O uso fica assim:

```
'Acesse o www.stackoverflow.com para tirar suas dúvidas.'.URLToAnchors();
```

Está espressão que criei deve servir para os mais diversos formatos de URL com search, comentários de URL, protocolo de segurança etc... Caso alguém tenha em mente melhorar algo por favor compartilhe o link permanente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar expressões regulares `regex`, para procurar por combinações na string, veja:

```
        str = "Lorem ipsum dolor www.stackoverflow.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
               Morbi sit amet ultricies nunc";
        var regexp = /(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}/gi;
        var matches_array = str.match(regexp);
```

[Exemplo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4hFh/)

Answer (score 1):

Tá aí a solucao, inclusive truncando URLs muito grandes para melhorar a exibicao

```
var expressao_regular_url = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;

function isUrl(texto)
{
    return expressao_regular_url.test(texto);
}

function urlTruncada(url)
{
    var limite_1 = 30;
    var limite_2 = 15;
    var reticencias = '[...]';
    if (url.length > limite_1 + limite_2 + reticencias.length)
    {
        url =
            url.substring(0, limite_1) + 
            reticencias + 
            url.substring(url.length - limite_2);
    }
    return url;
}

function autoUrl(texto)
{
    var texto_saida = '';
    var token = '';
    var caractere_fim_texto = String.fromCharCode(3);
    var separadores = ['\r', '\n', ' ', caractere_fim_texto];
    var caractere = '';
    var length_texto = texto.length;
    texto += caractere_fim_texto;
    for (var i in texto)
    {
        caractere = texto[i];
        if (separadores.indexOf(caractere) >= 0)
        {
            if (token)
            {
                if (isUrl(token))
                {
                    texto_saida += 
                        '<a href="' + (token.search('://') < 0 ? 'http://' : '') + token + '" target="_blank">' + 
                            urlTruncada(token) + 
                        '</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    texto_saida += token;
                }
                token = '';
                if (parseInt(i) < length_texto)
                {
                    texto_saida += caractere;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            token += caractere;
        }
    }
    return texto_saida;
}
```