# Identificar determinada url e alterar propriedade href com preg_match_all

Tags: php

Opa pessoal,

Estou com uma função que deve identificar uma determinada url. Caso a url seja identificada, ela deve ser envolvida com a tag `<a>` e sua propriedade `href` deve ter o valor igual ao da url passada. No caso, **quero que apenas uma url e seus diretórios sejam transformados em links**, ao passo que outras url diferentes continuem do mesmo jeito que estão.

Exemplo: A url que quero transformar em link sempre que aparecer no texto é: www.meusite.com.br

O problema que estou tendo é o seguinte: Na minha função, não estou conseguindo identificar a url sem o http. O que eu preciso é identificar a url com ou sem o protocoloco http e fazer com que o link tenha o seu href preenchido corretamente.

Preciso identificar os 3 casos abaixo, porém só consigo identificar o primeiro.

```
http://www.meusite.com.br
www.meusite.com.br
meusite.com.br
```

Lembrando que urls diferentes dessa não devem ser identificadas no filtro da função. Ex: meusite2.com.br **não** deve ser filtrado

Segue minha função com o que tentei:

```
    function checkUrl($text){
        $pattern = "(https?)?://[a-z0-9./&?:=%-_]*";

        preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
        if( count($matches[0]) > 0 ){
            foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                $text = str_replace($match, "<a href='" . $match . "' target='_blank'>" . $match . "</a>", $text);
            }
        }
        return $text;
    }

$text = "Em http://www.meusite.com.br você encontra muitas dicas sobre o assunto. Na url www.meusite.com.br você encontra especialistas com seus artigos esclarecdores. E claro, meusite.com.br é o melhor site no assunto";
```

Acredito que meu problema esteja somente na variável $pattern, em que passo o padrão a ser encontrado.

Pesquisei aqui no fórum, mas não encontrei exatamente o que eu precisava

[Identificar URLs e criar links](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12523/identificar-urls-e-criar-links)

O link acima não ajudou, e devo fazer isso no php.

Comment: Com `http` está funcionando corretamente?

Comment: Sim. Meu problema está quando retiro o http da url. Ele para de reconhecer :(

Comment: Só fiquei na dúvida pois no seu código ali esta com `https`...

Comment: aquela parte ali diz que tanto o http como o https podem ser usados. No caso o uso do s seria opcional.

Comment: Saquei, `RE` não é meu forte...rsrs

Comment: kkkk nem o meu, por isso to pedindo ajuda kkkkk

Comment: hahaha, acho que minha resposta deve ajudar...

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tratar antes para sempre ter `http` na url da seguinte forma:

```
function checkUrl($text){

    //primeiro garantindo que todos vão estar iguais
    $find = ['http://www.meusite.com.br', 'https://www.meusite.com.br', 'www.meusite.com.br'];
    $replace = "meusite.com.br";
    $text = string_replace($find, $replace, $text);

    //depois será possível colocar o http sem duplicar, caso já tivesse antes
    $find = ['meusite.com.br'];
    $replace = "http://www.meusite.com.br";
    $text = string_replace($find, $replace, $text);

    //e o que já estiver funcionando vai tratar tudo agora...
    $pattern = "(https?)?://[a-z0-9./&?:=%-_]*";

    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    if( count($matches[0]) > 0 ){
        foreach($matches[0] as $match){
            $text = str_replace($match, "<a href='" . $match . "' target='_blank'>" . $match . "</a>", $text);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```